# Filling an array with txt info

Tags: arrays, c, file, txt

I need to fill an array with info inside of a .txt file, an I got something (an yes, the code is in spanis, sorry but i'm in a latin country coding in college), and i forgot, the reason of why the for and everyting is in 10 is because my txt stores 10 names

```
#include <stdio.h>

void inicializarNombre (char* nombre) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; ++i) {
        nombre[i] = '\0';
    }
}

int main() {
    setbuf(stdout, 0);
    char *vectoristoNombres[10];
    char *vectoristoApellidos[10][20];

    FILE *nombres;
    nombres = fopen("nombres.txt" , "r");

    if(nombres == NULL) {
        perror("Error opening file");
        return(-1);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        vectoristoNombres[i] = "";
    }


    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        char caracter;
        char nombre[20];
        inicializarNombre(nombre);
        int index = 0;

        while ((caracter = fgetc(nombres)) != EOF) {
            if (caracter != '\n') {
                nombre[index] = caracter;
                index++;
            } else {
                vectoristoNombres[i] = nombre;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        printf("%s\n", vectoristoNombres[i]);
    }

    fclose(nombres);

    return 0;
}
```

The txt file is in this way:

```
data
secondData
yesMoreData
moreData
```

## The problem

The code reads the .txt file and store the data in the array, but I got one problem, when i store a new data input, replaces the previous data eg.

When i'm in the second iteration in the for, the array `vectositoNombres[]` should sotre

```
vectositoNombres[0] = "data"
vectositoNombres[1] = "secondData"
```

But instead of it, stores:

```
vectositoNombres[0] = "secondData"
vectositoNombres[1] = "secondData"
```

## I know and i've tried

After debugging I found that when I call `inicializarNombre()` the array `vectorsitonombres[]` gets empty

### Example

In the third iteration `vectorsitoNombres[]` should store

```
vectositoNombres[0] = "data"
vectositoNombres[1] = "secondData"
vectositoNombres[2] = "yesMoreData"
```

but it just stores:

```
vectositoNombres[0] = "yesMoreData"
vectositoNombres[1] = "yesMoreData"
vectositoNombres[2] = "yesMoreData"
```

and after call `inicializarNombre()` it turns:

```
vectositoNombres[0] = ""
vectositoNombres[1] = ""
vectositoNombres[2] = ""
```

Comment: In your second loop, each `vectoristoNombres[i]` is set to point to the same buffer, `nombre`, which contains the last line read. All the pointer values in `vectoristoNombres` are identical.

Comment: How do I fix that?, i've moved the vectorsitoNomrbes[i] = nombre out of the while and still doing the same (sorry if i don't understand  too much, idk much about buffers in c)

Comment: Each `vectoristoNombres[i]` has to point to a different buffer (or different places in a single bigger buffer). You could define `nombre` as `char nombre[10][20];`, read characters into `nombre[i][index]`, and set `vectoristoNombres[i] = nombre[i]`. Note, however, that `nombre` is defined within the scope of the second loop, but its address is still stored (repeatedly) in `vectoristoNombres` and used in the third loop (UB). Move `nombre`’s declaration outside the loop, giving it function scope.

Comment: And you have to `inicializarNombre(nombre[i]);` each time through the second loop. You wouldn’t have to initialize at all if you NUL-terminated `nombre[i]` when the newline was read (`nombre[i][index] = ‘\0’;`). All this ignores the potential buffer overflows if your text file has lines over 19 characters.

Comment: It worked, thank you very much. You solved it in a comment and not in an anwer, how do I thank you for it?

Comment: strdup(numbre) will fix it

Comment: @RicardoRoel You just did not here for the points.

Comment: @pm100 True, good option and would eliminate the `nombre` scope issue. Or `vectoristoNombres` elements could be allocated and used directly. But since OP was working with fixed buffers I answered it that way.